# SQL Laundry List

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I had someone ask me for a comprehensive list of configuration options for an x64 SQL Server install. besides just SQL config options, they were also looking for info on OS settings (server 2003 in particular).

i know where we could get bits and pieces of the information, but does any provide a comprehensive type list?

Answer (score 2):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx

Look for your version of SQL in there.

Comment: that's close, but it really is just an index of all the bits and pieces and doesn't seem to include OS configuration options. i've poked around there previously and will continue to do so, maybe i will be able to find two ror three useful links instead of the hundred it seems i need to browse.

Answer (score 0):

The only OS related item that I have encountered is with SQL 2005 Enterprise Edition and that is setting the server group policy to lock pages in memory for the SQL Server service account.

Comment: you dont need that option for x64

Comment: Are you sure about that? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918483

Comment: In Aug 2007 when researching the message "A significant part of sql server process memory has been paged out. This may result in a performance degradation." that was in our the sql (error) log, KB918483 indicated that granting 'lock pages in memory' to the SQL service account would correct this condition for SQL 2005 Enterprise Edition (and it did).  

BTW, our OS is Windows 2003 R2 Enterprise x64 and we run SQL 2005  EE (64-bit).